# Different SVG Icons rendering the same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack

I have two SVG icons I'm importing within my react application using "[react-svg-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-loader)"

The icons are imported as components with their own paths yet the output is the same for which ever icon is first in the code.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Navigation from '../Navigation/index.js';
import MainLogo from '../MainLogo/index.js';
import Search from '../Search/index.js';
import './index.css'; // styles from

import Logo from '../../assets/svg/logos/Voo_Main.svg';
import SearchIcon from '../../assets/svg/icons/search.svg';

export default class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    const { navItems } = this.props;

    return (
      <header className="header">

        <SearchIcon />
        <Logo />
      </header>
    );
  }
};
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Here is my loader within my webpack config:

```
// react-svg-loader
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-loader
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: [
             {
                 loader: "babel-loader",
             },
             {
                 loader: "react-svg-loader",
                 options: {
                     jsx: true, // true outputs JSX tags
                 },
             },
         ],
},
```

Here is the code for the SVG icons from the DOM:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <defs>
    <path id="a" d="M14.5 16A6.508 6.508 0 0 1 8 9.5C8 5.916 10.916 3 14.5 3S21 5.916 21 9.5 18.084 16 14.5 16m0-15C9.813 1 6 4.813 6 9.5c0 1.983.688 3.807 1.832 5.254l-6.539 6.539a.999.999 0 1 0 1.414 1.414l6.539-6.539A8.443 8.443 0 0 0 14.5 18c4.687 0 8.5-3.813 8.5-8.5C23 4.813 19.187 1 14.5 1"></path>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <mask id="b" fill="#fff">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#a"></use>
    </mask>
    <use fill="#D3D3D3" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#a"></use>
    <g fill="#121A28" mask="url(#b)">
      <path d="M0 24h24V0H0z"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Second icon:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="50" viewBox="0 0 120 50">
  <defs>
    <path id="a" d="M95.448 0c-6.967 0-13.25 2.905-17.717 7.567C73.262 2.905 66.979 0 60.01 0c-6.974 0-13.263 2.912-17.73 7.578C37.81 2.912 31.523 0 24.548 0 10.992 0 0 10.989 0 24.546c0 13.557 10.992 24.548 24.548 24.548 6.975 0 13.263-2.91 17.732-7.579 4.467 4.668 10.756 7.579 17.73 7.579 6.969 0 13.252-2.908 17.72-7.568 4.469 4.66 10.751 7.568 17.718 7.568 13.56 0 24.552-10.99 24.552-24.548C120 10.989 109.008 0 95.448 0M37.533 19.734l-9.664 14.84a3.968 3.968 0 0 1-3.327 1.8 3.967 3.967 0 0 1-3.33-1.8l-9.661-14.84a3.937 3.937 0 0 1 1.17-5.462 3.971 3.971 0 0 1 5.484 1.167l6.337 9.728 6.332-9.728a3.974 3.974 0 0 1 5.485-1.167 3.94 3.94 0 0 1 1.174 5.462m22.465 15.7c-6.018 0-10.898-4.878-10.898-10.898 0-6.018 4.88-10.899 10.898-10.899 6.021 0 10.903 4.88 10.903 10.9 0 6.02-4.88 10.897-10.903 10.897m35.438 0c-6.018 0-10.898-4.878-10.898-10.898 0-6.018 4.88-10.899 10.898-10.899 6.021 0 10.902 4.88 10.902 10.9 0 6.02-4.88 10.897-10.902 10.897"></path>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <mask id="b" fill="#fff">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#a"></use>
    </mask>
    <use fill="#FEFEFE" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#a"></use>
    <g fill="#D4107A" mask="url(#b)">
      <path d="M0 0h120v50H0z"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That looks like identical ids are referenced. To test, inspect the DOM of the rendered page. If the elements of the icons have the form `<use xlink:href="#..." />` with identical references, then [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo), which is part of the loader plugin, has probably played havock with them. Try seting option `cleanupIDs: false`.

Comment: @ccprog Thank you for this, I've added the cleanupIDs to the webpack config options for svg-loader to no avail. I also added the DOM output of the SVG icons. The icons do have identical id's as "#a" hence the same output.

Comment: I took the liberty to reformat. It's as I thought: `<use xlink:href="#a">` is used in both icons. Are these the same ids as used in the original files? It still looks suspiciouly like the renaming convention SVGO uses to me.

Comment: I'm using the same plugin react-svg-loader in another project and I haven't had this issue before. The only difference here is that I'm downloading the SVG's as assets from Zeplin rather than provided by a designer. I will check the code of the SVG icon.

Comment: @ccprog Found the culprit it was Zeplin adding these tags as when I got the icons exported manually from Illustrator the issue does not persist. Thank you for your help

Comment: Just a small comment: If you convert the svg into a jsx element, the process of rendering them becomes a no-mess-no-fuss experience.

Comment: @Andrew If I understand you correctly I would assume that's how I'm doing it already however, you'd need a svg loader with in your app otherwise the icon will not render. Do you have an article regarding your reference?

Comment: @Filth .jsx supports svg tags natively. I can show you an example. It's not a solution so don't mark it as the answer. I use many SVGs in my apps but don't have a single .svg file in my code base

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the SVG to a .jsx file and modify the attributes so it's .jsx-friendly, it will render the SVGs as if it were a .svg file.

```
import * as React from 'react';

const svg = (
    <div>
        <svg 
            width="120" 
            height="50" 
            viewBox="0 0 120 50"
        >
            <defs>
                <path 
                    id="a" 
                    d="M95.448 0c-6.967 0-13.25 
                    2.905-17.717 7.567C73.262 2.905 66.979 0 
                    60.01 0c-6.974 0-13.263 2.912-17.73 7.578C37.81 
                    2.912 31.523 0 24.548 0 10.992 0 0 10.989 0 24.546c0 
                    13.557 10.992 24.548 24.548 24.548 6.975 0 13.263-2.91 
                    17.732-7.579 4.467 4.668 10.756 7.579 17.73 7.579 6.969 
                    0 13.252-2.908 17.72-7.568 4.469 4.66 10.751 7.568 17.718 
                    7.568 13.56 0 24.552-10.99 24.552-24.548C120 10.989 109.008 
                    0 95.448 0M37.533 19.734l-9.664 14.84a3.968 3.968 0 0 1-3.327 
                    1.8 3.967 3.967 0 0 1-3.33-1.8l-9.661-14.84a3.937 3.937 0 0 1 
                    1.17-5.462 3.971 3.971 0 0 1 5.484 1.167l6.337 
                    9.728 6.332-9.728a3.974 3.974 0 0 1 5.485-1.167 3.94 3.94 0 
                    0 1 1.174 5.462m22.465 15.7c-6.018 0-10.898-4.878-10.898-10.898 
                    0-6.018 4.88-10.899 10.898-10.899 6.021 0 10.903 4.88 10.903 
                    10.9 0 6.02-4.88 10.897-10.903 10.897m35.438 0c-6.018 
                    0-10.898-4.878-10.898-10.898 0-6.018 4.88-10.899 10.898-10.899 
                    6.021 0 10.902 4.88 10.902 10.9 0 6.02-4.88 10.897-10.902 10.897"
                />
            </defs>
            <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                <mask id="b" fill="#fff">
                    <use xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlinkHref="#a"/>
                </mask>
                <use fill="#FEFEFE"/>
                <g fill="#D4107A" mask="url(#b)">
                    <path d="M0 0h120v50H0z"/>
                </g>
            </g >
        </svg >
    </div>
);
```

[image]

Excuse the blue background. That's the background color I have in my test dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue - it seems that different SVGs used the same path id.

This is how I solved it - changed each SVG file to **use** different ID:

In your case - you should change the second SVG:

`<path id="a"` to `<path id="b"`

AND

`<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#a"></use>`

to

`<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#b"></use>`

AND

`<use fill="#D3D3D3" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#a"></use>`

to

`<use fill="#D3D3D3" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#b"></use>`